# Error Running GWT on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

i had a problem running Internationalization code (GWT teck. on Eclipse) and had the following console result

```
Jul 16, 2014 9:45:11 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[WARN] Server class 'org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Dev/eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0/gwt-2.6.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
```

Searching online found out something about creating new key 
              HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Prefs
if So  then how to create this KEY??
and what exactly causes this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are WARN lines, so they shouldn't cause any compilation or runtime problem and your project should eventually compile and run.

It seems some code in your server wants to store something using the [java.util.prefs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) api and it is failing because your preferences repository has some problems (maybe permissions, or it is full, etc) or the class using it is storing something wrong.

The GWT compiler, stores some info in your java preferences as well, but it does it in compile time, so if it failed you should see a different line, see [CheckForUpdates](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/CheckForUpdates.java#256) class.

Other WARN lines in your logs are normal in dev-mode.